# Content-based image retrieval features

Tags: image-processing, google-image-search, cbir, lire

I'm trying to implement Content-based image retrieval in my application. I found a LIRE library that look pretty good.

I need to analyze my image collection for similar(from human point of view) images. In my catalog I have a big amount of absolutely different uncategorized/unstructured images

In order to analyze images LIRE contains following list of algorithms:

```
        CEDD,
        AutoColorCorrelogram,
        BinaryPatternsPyramid,
        ColorLayout,
        EdgeHistogram,
        FCTH,
        FuzzyColorHistogram,
        Gabor,
        JCD,
        JointHistogram,
        JpegCoefficientHistogram,
        LocalBinaryPatterns,
        LuminanceLayout,
        OpponentHistogram,
        PHOG,
        RankAndOpponent,
        RotationInvariantLocalBinaryPatterns,
        ScalableColor,
        SimpleCentrist,
        SimpleColorHistogram,
        SPACC,
        SpatialPyramidCentrist,
        SPCEDD,
        SPFCTH,
        SPJCD,
        SPLBP,
        Tamura
```

Based on your experience, could you please recommend one of them that can be most suitable(from human point of view) for such kind of image suite(mix of uncategorized images) in order to find a similar images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `JCD` is the best one because combine two approach at the same time, and each approach is combining two features (color & texture).

Comment: @alexanoid I need the C# code for one method of them. Can you help me?